# Computing Inner Product

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra

Hi I am trying to compute an inner product in Fortran. I provide a sample code below and explain the output I am getting, and the expected output.  The code itself compiles with no errors, however the output I obtain is not what I am expecting.  I think am not properly coding the inner product.  The code is below.

EDIT: I edited the code based on the help obtained in the comments below.

```
program

integer :: i,j
integer, parameter :: nx = 10, ny = 10
complex, dimension(-nx:nx,-ny:ny) :: A,v
real :: B

    B = 0.0

    do j = -ny+1,ny-1
    do i = -nx+1,nx-1

         A(i,j) = v(i+1,j)+v(i-1,j)+v(i,j+1)+v(i,j-1)-4*v(i,j)

         B = B + conjg(A(i,j))*A(i,j) !computing the inner product

    end do 
    end do

    print *, 'Result of the inner product of A with itself', B

end program
```

Am I computing the inner product correct now?  Thanks.

Note: The trace of a matrix product is an inner product, e.g Frobenius inner product.just a generalization of the inner product to tensors of rank 2, Acts identical to the product between rank 1 tensors

Comment: Why should the answer be `1`?  That would depend on the value of `v`, which you don't show.  Anyway, you have a rather suspicious `b=0; b=b+...`.

Comment: @francescalus I updated the code showing the value of v, if that will help.  Isn't the inner product between the same two vectors = 1?  What is suspicious about that?  In order to compute the inner product, I need to sum over all i,j; so I thought that in order to do the sum I will start B at zero and then compute the inner product this way, since B must be a real scalar.  Why is it wrong?  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Essentially: you aren't summing over all i,j: just the last pair: that `b=0` is resetting the sum every iteration.  You'll want to just stick that `b=0` _before_ the loops rather than in them.

Comment: The inner product of a vector with itself is the square of its magnitude.

Comment: @francescalus Okay, I edited my above code based on your suggestion.  I moved the B=0 before the loops rather than in them.  Is the inner product being calculated correctly now?  I realize it should not be equal to 1 since I didn't impose normalization.  I also realize so many of my problems in fortran always consist of moving something in or out of a do loop. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you use the built-in `dot_product(a,b)` function for vectors, and `matmul(A,B)` for matrices?

Comment: `A` is square matrix. How do you define the inner product of a matrix? Are you confusing it with matrix multiplication?

Comment: @ja72 Matrix multiplication of this form is equivalent to an inner product, the Trace of (A^T A) is an inner product, even though A  is a  matrix. The trace of a product of matrices behaves similarly to a dot product of vectors.  However I may be confused and you very well may be right, which is why I posted this post.

Comment: @francescalus I saw your comment but now I can't see it anymore.  In regards to your first question, Yes I intend Derive to return an array, it is a 2D array and I want it to be saved like that.  Secondly, with or without having implicit none in the function I still get the same error message.  I am referring to this post in which you just commented on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664659/compilation-errors-from-using-module-subroutine-and-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to compute the inner product of two matrices? Could you define that?

In any case if you want to calculate the inner product of two vectors if Fortran, you could write

```
prod = sum( A * B )
```

Where, `A` and `B` are conformable arrays of a type for which multiplication is defined (real, complex, etc.), and `prod` is a variable of the **same** type.

If `A` and `B` are one-dimensional, this calculates their *inner product*. I don't know what it is called otherwise.

**EDIT**

Based of the definition you provided ("Tr(A^\dagger A) = A_{ij}A^*_{ij} =Tr(AA^\dagger)"), you have got the bounds wrong. Put the inner product in a separate loop with

```
do i = -nx,nx
  do j = -ny,ny
    B = B + conjg(A(i,j))*A(i,j) !computing the inner product
  end do
end do
```

Or use

```
B = sum( conjg(A)*A )
```

without a loop.

Comment: The trace of a matrix product is an inner product, e.g Frobenius inner product.just a generalization of the inner product to tensors of rank 2, Acts identical to the product between rank 1 tensors

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However I am more interested in knowing if my sample code in my above question is correct. That was the point of my question, is it correct? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you know what the trace of a matrix product is? I can see clearly you have no clue

Comment: @Integrals, I am saying this based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product. If you have another definition, please provide it.

Comment: Well I don't loop over the end points because those are already taken care of in my boundary conditions. Hence why my loops are written as they are. Otherwise great thanks a lot for the edit! I will check it as the answer I just want to wait to see if VladimirF reposts his answer again. So I can compare the two solutions and see what works best for me. But this makes sense, thanks

Comment: Also, your loops should first be over j, then i. Since the array is A(i,j), the code will actually run faster if you switch your loop order. (I learned this on stack overflow I don't actually know it my self)

Comment: By the way, I don't actually see any big difference in your answer and my posted question, if anything my code is more efficient . My loops are over what they should be, and the ordering of my loops is actually more efficient than yours. So your code is actually less helpful than what I have I realize, and it'll also run slower!. What is helpful is that you provided an alternative way, using Sum. For some reason I never think to use intrinsic functions. Thanks!